# Django and Openx?

Tags: django, django-templates, openx

Somebody know how use [OpenX](http://www.openx.org/) (php app) with Django? I need to use OpenX or a similar software for displaying ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement Openx using javascript, so as long as you run Openx on a php server, that should be easy.

Header, something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://something.here/delivery/spcjs.php?id=1&amp;block=1'></script>
```

And then, something like this where you want to put you ad.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    OA_show(1);
</script>
<noscript>
    <a target='_blank' href='http://something.here/delivery/ck.php?n=112bda3'>
    <img border='0' alt='' src='http://something.here/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1&amp;n=112bda3' /></a>
</noscript>
```

OpenX generates all this code for you.

Answer (score 3):

As Tomsky answered you don't need any special software just to display ads - you can just use javascript.

However, if you want to access the server and manipulate the OpenX objects such as campaigns, banners, advertisers, etc, you will need some kind of remote API. For that OpenX Source provides a XML-RPC API but I also developed a REST API:
http://www.openxrest.com

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a project](http://code.google.com/p/django-openx/) that gives you API integration. If you only want to serve ads, you don't need it though, you just have to paste the javascript provided by OpenX.